# mongo Using a $match within an $and

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to use an $and within a $match and can't seem to get it correct. The syntax I'm using isn't correct.

```
{
"$match":
{
                "$expr": {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "$match": {
                        "contra": {
                          "$exists": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                      "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$isActivation", true
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
}
}
```

Comment: Post full query with some sample documents for correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as this:

```js
{
    "$match": {
        "contractId": { "$exists": true },
        "isActive": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even skip the `$and`

Comment: Oh yes! Got carried away. Thanks.